# A shorter person with a normal sized tallis katan

Tags: halacha, shiurim-measurements, tallit-katan, size

A theoretical question: If a young person (a boy for example that is 13 yrs old) that happens to be very short (not because of any physical disability) wears a normal size tallis katan it will be very long on him. May he wear a tallis katan that doesn't have a proper shiur for a normal person and make a bracha on it and still fulfill the mitzvah?

Comment: Isn't the halacha that the size is one that if a small child would go out with this beged alone he would be covered?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Aruch Hashulchan 1:16:5,](https://www.sefaria.org/Aruch_HaShulchan.1.16.5?with=all&lang=bi) there is no official size for a talit katan, and therefore, one can make a blessing as long as the tzitzit is big enough for him: (Others disagree)

> ולעניות דעתי כל חקירה זו בחינם, והעולם מקיימים מצות ציצית בטליתות הקטנים. דכבר בארנו בריש סימן ח מהנימוקי יוסף ומהריטב"א, שיש מהראשונים שאמרו דציצית אינה אלא בבגד שמעטף הראש ורוב הגוף. ולפי זה כל טליתות קטנות שלנו אינם חייבות בציצית. ונדחו דבריהם, ומן התורה כל בגד של ארבע כנפות שנושא על גופו – חייב בציצית, עיין שם. וגם דעת רבינו הבית יוסף כן הוא, כמו שכתבתי שם. והא דבעינן עיטוף רוב הגוף – זהו בטלית העליון, שהוא כמו הסודר שבזמן הגמרא, שהיה הילוכם בזה כידוע. ולכן מברכינן עלייהו "להתעטף בציצית". ובזה בעינן שיעור מפני שהוא על הבגדים. אבל טלית קטן שתחת הבגדים אינה צריכה שיעור כלל, דאם רק יש בו ארבע כנפות – חייב בציצית. וכן מבואר להדיא מדברי הריטב"א והנימוקי יוסף שהבאנו בשם בסעיף ד, עיין שם.

**Halacha Le'Maaseh:**

- Sephardim: One has fulfilled the mitzvah BUT cannot make a bracha on it when wearing Tzitzit measuring 1.5 amot by 1 amah. It would be preferable if this shiur did not include a neck hole, but if it does and it is difficult to find Tzitzit that size or they are uncomfortable to wear, one may rely on the opinions that say the neck hole is included. In this case, one should make a bracha on a Tallit Gadol and patur (exempt) the Tallit Katan by doing so. In order to make a bracha on a Tallit Katan, it should measure 2 amot (37.8") by 1 amah (18.9")[63].
- Ashkenazim: In order to follow the Mishna Brurah, one should wear Tzitzit that are 1.5 amot (in length) by 0.5 amah (in width) not including the neck hole. [64] Accordingly, one can wear Tzitzit that are 32 by 16 inches not including the neck hole.

See [Halachipedia](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Tzitzit#Size_Requirements) for sources.